# How do I use metadata in `not-found.tsx` in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, metadata, next.js13

In my NextJS app, I have a `not-found.tsx` file with some simple metadata in the root of my `app` directory:

```
import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Page not found",
};

export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="mb-4 text-xl">Page not found</h1>
      <Link href="/">
        <button className="rounded bg-blue-600 px-3 py-1 text-sm text-gray-50 dark:bg-blue-700">
          Back to home
        </button>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

But when I enter a wrong URL, I see the URL itself as the title of the page, rather than `Page not found`. I checked the `head` element, and there's no `title` element in it.

How can I export a metadata object from a not found page?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Next.js doesn't support it yet, see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45620

Comment: The workaround mentioned in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45620#issuecomment-1488933853 should work for setting the page's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not yet supported as of Jun 25, 2023

Comment: Any reference on this?

Comment: here's the [reference](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45620#issuecomment-1493336055)